# What do you call a process that will not complete?

Tags: naming

As we know, some processes will complete.

```
void func (var a) { Console.WriteLine(a) };
```

And some will not,

```
void func (var a) { while (true) { Console.WriteLine(a) } };
```

What do we call the function that completes?

What do we call the function that never completes?

Comment: Broken, or bugged

Comment: Not everything has to have a name. If there is a name for non-terminating functions in some subfield, that term will not enable clear communication with the majority of people outside of that subfield. Most programs do not feature infinite loops, so this isn't much of an issue.

Comment: Hello Code Whisperer, do you have an actual problem to be solved? And askers here are expected to do some reasearch before they ask.  For example, did you look tinto [this Wikipedia article about infinite loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop)? If not, maybe it answers your question already? Or maybe you are looking for the term "termination of a process", which is often used in this context?

Comment: In the context of multithreading, this can be called _a task_.

Comment: @mouviciel, a "function that never completes" is called a "*task*"?

Comment: @Steve - This is a bit provocative. In RTOS and multithreading, tasks usually are functions whose body is an infinite loop.

Comment: @mouviciel, I wasn't meaning it to sound like fighting words. I take your point that infinite loops may feature where a program is designed to process continuous input (or continuously await input), but I wouldn't (in computing generally) recognise the word "task" as implying specifically a procedure with such a never-ending loop that cannot be exited (except of course by a hard abort of a process or thread, or by pulling the plug).

Comment: For my part also, I would say there is no specific name for such a function. If the function is truly never-ending but contains the main program, you might call it the "main loop" (of the program/thread/task) which tends to imply that it loops indefinitely if not infinitely, but that is more a reference to the loop itself (as a control flow structure), not a type of function which contains such a loop, since looping is the job of loops, not of functions (unless the function calls itself recursively, in which case it might be called an "infinitely recursive function").

Answer (score 4):

[Rust refers to functions that have special syntax to indicate they do not return as “diverging functions”](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/functions.html). The term comes from diverging sequences in maths, which are effectively infinite, never ending, sequences.

I’m not aware of another term for the same thing in other languages, so diverging functions or diverging processes seems a reasonable choice as a generic term for such functionality.

Comment: The term “diverge” is also used by B. Pierce in “Types and Programming Languages” in the context of typing recursive functions: In a Hindley–Miller type system, the function `letrec diverge _ = diverge ()` has type `Unit → T` for all types T, and therefore `diverge ()` is a bottom value for all types, e.g. `undefined` in Haskell. But this term is not widespread outside of Rust, type theory, or process calculi. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(computer_science)